# How to configure network on EC2 instance launched by Vagrant?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, vagrant, amazon-vpc

This is my AWS setup:

- 1 VPC with:

  - default public subnet, 10.0.0.0/24

    - 1 EC2 micro instance, private 10.0.0.172 and public Elastic IP
  - 1 RDS instance, running MySQL

The EC2 instance has network connection to the outside world (verified with `ping 8.8.8.8`). This is it's routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         ip-10-0-0-1.eu- 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
instance-data.e *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

The EC2 instance can also connect to the RDS instance.

What I want, is to launch a second EC2 instance (Amazon Linux AMI 2014.03.1 64bit) from inside the first EC2 instance, using Vagrant. The second EC2 instance should be in the same VPC subnet but it's actual IP address doesn't matter much. It also doesn't need a public Elastic IP. It does need to connect to the outside world, to install software using `yum`.

This is my `Vagrantfile`:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "dummy"

  config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    aws.access_key_id = "ACCESS_KEY_ID"
    aws.secret_access_key = "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
    aws.keypair_name = "KEYPAIR_NAME"

    aws.ami = "ami-2918e35e"
    aws.instance_type = "m1.small"
    aws.region = "eu-west-1"

    aws.subnet_id = "subnet-SUBNETID"
    aws.security_groups = "sg-SECURITYGROUPID"


    override.ssh.username = "ec2-user"
    override.ssh.private_key_path = "PRIVATE_KEY.pem"
  end

  config.ssh.pty = true
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh"
end
```

In the shell script `provision.sh` I install some software:

```
yum install -y subversion
```

This fails, because `yum` can't connect to the outside network.

When I do `vagrant ssh` and check the IP address, it's in the 10.0.0.0/24 range and I can ping in either direction between the two EC2 instances (ICMP was allowed in the security group). I can't `ping 8.8.8.8` and I can't `yum install` software because the instance can't reach the repositories. I checked the `route` and it's identical to that of the first instance.

Also, in the AWS web console, the second instance doesn't have a public IP address.

When I add this line to my `Vagrantfile`:

```
aws.associate_public_ip = true
```

then I get the following error on `vagrant up --provider=aws --provision`:

```
There are errors in the configuration of this machine. Please fix
the following errors and try again:

AWS Provider:
* The following settings shouldn't exist: associate_public_ip
```

and the instance does not launch.

So my question is: how can I give the vagrant instance a network connection, without using an Elastic IP?

Comment: I think I have found the anser to my question here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/issues/242

In short: the `associate_public_ip` feature isn't in the public release of the `vagrant-aws` plugin yet.

Answer (score 1):

in my installation that parameter was not exist but there is

```
aws.elastic_ip = true
```

that has the same purpose.

To find the real fields used in your plugins chech this file

```
~/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-0.4.1/lib/vagrant-aws/config.rb
```

of course I have the vagrant-aws-0.4.1 change with yours

Comment: @davidski on Github explains ```aws.elastic_ip``` vs ```associate_public_ip```:

They're very similar, but not quite identical. Elastic IPs are primarily static assignments which you "own" and can assign to instances as those hosts come and go, providing a static IP reference you can use again and again. Public IPs are only valid for the life of an instance. If you bring up a new instance, you'll get a random public IP address. There is a default limit of 10 Elastic IPs per account and you pay for any Elastic IPs you have checked out (allocated) but which are not in use by an active instance.